How to build a React/Nivo line chart with data from Rest API
I am extremely new to react and I'd like to use nivo to build some charts based on data pulled from a REST API that i am also building. I'm able to show the chart by importing their mock data, however when i try to replace the mock data with my data from REST, I receive an error saying 'Cannot read properties of null (reading 'filter')'.
This is my LineChart component (I am pulling the mock data in as mockdata, and my rest data in as data):
import { ResponsiveLine } from "@nivo/line";
import { mockLineData as mockdata } from "../data/mockData";
import useApi from "../hooks/useApi";

const LineChart = () => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useApi("/data");

  return (
    <ResponsiveLine
      data={mockdata}
      margin={{ top: 50, right: 110, bottom: 50, left: 60 }}
      xScale={{ type: "point" }}
      yScale={{
        type: "linear",
        min: "auto",
        max: "auto",
        stacked: true,
        reverse: false,
      }}
      yFormat=" >-.2f"
      axisTop={null}
      axisRight={null}
      axisBottom={{
        tickSize: 5,
        tickPadding: 5,
        tickRotation: 0,
        legend: "transportation",
        legendOffset: 36,
        legendPosition: "middle",
        truncateTickAt: 0,
      }}
      axisLeft={{
        tickSize: 5,
        tickPadding: 5,
        tickRotation: 0,
        legend: "count",
        legendOffset: -40,
        legendPosition: "middle",
        truncateTickAt: 0,
      }}
      pointSize={10}
      pointColor={{ theme: "background" }}
      pointBorderWidth={2}
      pointBorderColor={{ from: "serieColor" }}
      pointLabel="data.yFormatted"
      pointLabelYOffset={-12}
      enableTouchCrosshair={true}
      useMesh={true}
      legends={[
        {
          anchor: "bottom-right",
          direction: "column",
          justify: false,
          translateX: 100,
          translateY: 0,
          itemsSpacing: 0,
          itemDirection: "left-to-right",
          itemWidth: 80,
          itemHeight: 20,
          itemOpacity: 0.75,
          symbolSize: 12,
          symbolShape: "circle",
          symbolBorderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)",
          effects: [
            {
              on: "hover",
              style: {
                itemBackground: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .03)",
                itemOpacity: 1,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ]}
    />
  );
};

export default LineChart;

I am able to see the chart with mockdata, but if i replace data ={mockdata} with data = {data} i receive the error.
I also created a dummy component to compare the two json payloads (mockdata vs data) and display them using JSON.stringify(data). I verified with JSON Diff that they are identical.
I assume the error is due to the chart not receiving the data in the structure it is expecting, but based on the fact that data and mockdata seem to be identical, I cant figure out what the difference could be. Any ideas? Is there a data type issue that could cause this? I am assuming data and mockdata are both the same datatype.

Issue is likely in your useApi hook, where you call filter on initial data, which you set to null before any data is fetched.
